# jQuery Datatable with colored rows

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, datatable

I need to create a jQuery datatable, in which some rows might have gray background color - meaning that they are disactivated. A row can have gray background only if the column 'status' of the corresponding MySQL table is equal to 0.

Look at the below code. Column '10' is hidden. It contains `status` value. If it is 0, then the row should have different background color. But this does not work. No error message. Any ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
              $('#newspaper-b').dataTable({
              "sPaginationType":"full_numbers",
              "aaSorting":[[4, "asc"]],
              "aoColumns": [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,
                            {"bSearchable": true, "bVisible": false},null,null],
              "bJQueryUI":true,
              'fnRowCallback': function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
                    if(aData[10]=="0"){
                        nRow.className = "disactivatedRow";
                    }
                    return nRow;
                }
              });
```

**CSS**

```
.disactivatedRow td { 
    background-color:#ffbba9 !important;
    color: #e6e6fa;
}
#newspaper-b {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-color: #B7DDF2;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
    width: 480px;
}
#newspaper-b th {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EBF4FB;
    border-color: lightgray;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 15px 10px 10px;
}
#newspaper-b tbody tr td {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
}
#newspaper-b td {
    border-top: 1px dashed #FFFFFF;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 10px;
}
#newspaper-b tbody tr:hover td {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFCF8B;
    color: #000000;
}
#newspaper-b tbody tr.selected td {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFCF8B;
    color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: CSS with "markedrow" rule is required here.

Comment: @Denis Chmel: Yes, sure I have CSS style defined for it. Sorry that I have not posted it. Please look at the update. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Row doesn't have content hence background, td should be colored instead:

```
.disactivatedRow td { 
    background-color:#ffbba9 !important;
    color: #e6e6fa;
}
```

If still doesn't solve I'd suggest you to console.log(aData[10]) outside of your if. For console.log to work use Chrome/Firefox, find console output via F12 and see what aData[10] contains, maybe you need aData[9] (programmers use to count from zero ;).

Comment: Thanks. aData[10] is correct. I've already checked it. I tried your solution, but still the rows are not colored. Please look at my complete CSS in the updated post.

Comment: Ok, the next step is to use "Inspect element" (in Chrome out of the box, in Firefox after installing Firebug). Right-click your cell, choose "Inspect element", track wrong cascading of styles on the right pane. However, usually "!important" has the biggest priority, so your problem may be that the row doesn't get a correct classname, this is still can be seen when inspecting (on the left pane, where generated HTML is shown)

Comment: Yes,that's the case. When I select the row that has status=0, I see that the style 'disactivatedRow' is not applied to it (CSS window of Firebug). So, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: But when I leave just '.disactivatedRow td', even in this case this style is not applied. Maybe I should do something like this: #newspaper-b tr.disactivatedRow td {...} ?

Comment: See left pain of inspector, I bet there's no <tr class="disactivatedRow"> while it should be (BTW try to add it inside code in inspector - to check it will affect on background). If class present and no background - I give up :)

Comment: Yeah, there is <tr id="BC125" class="edit_tr even">. If I substitute it with <tr id="BC125" class="disactivatedRow">, it gives the expected result. So, how can I disactivate this "edit_tr even", which most probably comes from jQuery UI?

Comment: It's ok to have other classes - you use "!impotant" and it should override anything else. The problem is that disactivatedRow class is missing and this means only that your "if" never triggers. Debug  why via console.log().
FYI also, nRow.className = "..." will replace existing classes, if you need to add new, use $(nRow).addClass("...")

Comment: Don't mess with possible CSS troubles. Use $(nRow).remove() instead of adding class while debugging if, and make those rows disappear first.

Comment: They don't disappear in case of using $(nRow).remove() and that's terrible. I tried aData[0], aData[10]...well,I'm sure about values of aData, but I have no idea why it does not work.

Comment: Outside of "if" write $("td", nRow).html(aData[10] == "0" ? "deleted" : "exists");

Comment: Thanks a lot. There was my error. Two <td> elements had <span id="8_<?php echo $flightNum; ?>" - i.e. the same number 8 as identifier. Now it works fine!